# calculating cannibalization rate in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hey guys I am working on a table that contains the following columns.

| CustomerID | Zip | UUID | Year | Qrtr | Mth | StoreNum | 1stStore | NextStore | CustomerHistory | ReturnStatus | ActiveStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to find the cannibalization rate of customers from one store to another. I have managed to identify customers who visited the primary store (the original store) and then visited another store (the competitor store) within a given time frame.

To calculate the cannibalization rate of customers, I have identified customers who have visited both the primary store and its competitor store, and then I will compare the percentage of overlapping customers to the total number of customers at the primary store.

Here's an example formula to calculate the cannibalization rate of customers:

Cannibalization Rate = (Number of Overlapping Customers / Total Number of Customers at Primary Store) * 100

Where:

1. Number of Overlapping Customers: the count of unique customers who have visited both the primary store and its competitor store
2. Total Number of Customers at Primary Store: the count of unique customers who have visited the primary store.

This is the code I have so far

```
SELECT 
  t1.StoreNum AS StoreNum,
  t2.StoreNum AS CompetitorStore,
  t1.Year,
  t1.Quarter,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t1.CustomerID) AS StoreCustomers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t2.CustomerID) AS CompetitorCustomers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID, t1.CustomerID, NULL)) AS OverlapCustomers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID AND t1.ReturnStatus_Qtr = 'RETURNED', t1.CustomerID, NULL)) AS OverlapReturnedCustomers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID AND t1.ActiveStatus_Qtr = 'ACTIVE', t1.CustomerID, NULL)) AS OverlapActiveCustomers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t1.ReturnStatus_Qtr = 'RETURNED', t1.CustomerID, NULL)) AS StoreReturnedCustomers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t2.ReturnStatus_Qtr = 'RETURNED', t2.CustomerID, NULL)) AS CompetitorReturnedCustomers,
  IF(COUNT(DISTINCT t1.CustomerID, t2.CustomerID) > 0,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID, t1.CustomerID, NULL)) / COUNT(DISTINCT t1.CustomerID, t2.CustomerID),
    0
  ) AS CannibalizationRate
FROM 
  My_Table t1
  INNER JOIN My_Table t2 ON t1.Zip_Code = t2.Zip_Code 
    AND t1.Year = t2.Year
    AND t1.Quarter = t2.Quarter
    AND t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
    AND t1.StoreNum <> t2.StoreNum 
WHERE 
  t1.Year = <year>
  AND t1.Quarter = <quarter> 
  AND t1.StoreNum = <store_num> 
GROUP BY 
  t1.StoreNum,
  t2.StoreNum,
  t1.Year,
  t1.Quarter
```

but for some reason I am getting 1 in CannibalizationRate for all the rows, and I don't understand why. Does anyone know a better way to calculate the cannibalization rate? Or maybe you can identify what I am doing wrong in the code. A friend of mine said I need to aggregate columns, but I don't know what he means by that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How did you identify the `primary store` in your query? you used INNER JOIN with T1.CustomerId=T2.CustomerId: they will then always be the same for every row. Try using a LEFT join (the LEFT table is the primary store)

Comment: What is the purpose of `1stStore` & `NextStore` in that table (seems like an odd table design as you also have `storenum`) plus, you have this requirement in the join `t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID` so all the IF logic using that same condition is redundant.

Comment: challenge all conditions of the join e.g. is it actually important that (Quarter = Quarter ) or should it be Quarter >= Quarter ? (and this raises the prospect that Year + month need to be treated as dates e.g. 2023-01-01 is gerater than 2022-12-01)

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but might not satisfy as an answer.

Condense the problem into a more concise but representative set. For example I have setup some clients that have a first store identified, but who have also been to other stores (and you probably need some who have not been to other stores etc.). Once you have the set consider what represents the "baseline" (the "first store customers") and than the conditions absolutely needed for the self-joined table to link to the customers using other stores. Examine the raw data that the join produces - will this reveal what you are looking for? An example follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    CustomerID INT,
    Zip INT,
    Year INT,
    Qrtr INT,
    Mth INT,
    StoreNum INT,
    FirstStore INT
);
```

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (CustomerID, Zip, Year, Qrtr, Mth, StoreNum, FirstStore)
VALUES
  (12345, 90210, 2022, 3, 9, 6789, 6789)
, (12345, 90210, 2022, 3, 9, 1234, NULL)
, (12345, 90210, 2022, 3, 9, 5678, NULL)
, (78654, 90210, 2022, 3, 9, 1234, 1234)
, (78654, 90210, 2022, 3, 9, 6789, NULL)
, (78654, 90210, 2022, 3, 9, 5678, NULL)
, (22222, 90210, 2022, 3, 9, 5678, 5678)
;
```

```
select
*
from mytable as firsts
left join mytable as others ON firsts.year = others.year
       AND firsts.mth = others.mth
       AND firsts.CustomerID <> others.CustomerID
       AND firsts.StoreNum <> others.StoreNum
where firsts.firststore = firsts.storenum
order by firsts.CustomerID, firsts.StoreNum, others.storenum
```

| customerid | zip | year | qrtr | mth | storenum | firststore | customerid | zip | year | qrtr | mth | storenum | firststore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 6789 | 6789 | 78654 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 1234 | 1234 |
| 12345 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 6789 | 6789 | 22222 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 5678 | 5678 |
| 12345 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 6789 | 6789 | 78654 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 5678 | *null* |
| 22222 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 5678 | 5678 | 12345 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 1234 | *null* |
| 22222 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 5678 | 5678 | 78654 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 1234 | 1234 |
| 22222 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 5678 | 5678 | 78654 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 6789 | *null* |
| 22222 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 5678 | 5678 | 12345 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 6789 | 6789 |
| 78654 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 1234 | 1234 | 22222 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 5678 | 5678 |
| 78654 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 1234 | 1234 | 12345 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 5678 | *null* |
| 78654 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 1234 | 1234 | 12345 | 90210 | 2022 | 3 | 9 | 6789 | 6789 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KsiY2TtL)

**NB** I have had t make many assumptions about the data, it is only to help illustrate an approach.